# Recovering a directory from a corrupted btrfs partition without the root set

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I'm trying to recover data from a btrfs partition where the media was physically damaged.

I was able to recover about 99% of the partition, so I'm confident that most of the data should be there. But I seem to be missing important metadata. I wasn't able to mount the partition at all. `btrfs rescue super-recover` failed. I can get various files using `btrfs restore`, using different tree roots found by `btrfs-find-root`. However, for one directory (`/home`) this does always fail:

```
checksum verify failed on 965984256 found 000000B6 wanted 00000000
bad tree block 965984256, bytenr mismatch, want=965984256, have=0
Error searching -5
Error searching /recovery/sde1/@home
```

Since I cannot get into that directory from a root set, I wonder whether there are other ways to get the directory contents, bypassing the root set metadata - maybe by scanning the whole partition.

Answer (score 0):

If the data itself is corrupted, parts of the files will have bad or inaccessible data. If this is the case, we will see checksum errors in the log. To some extent, `BTRFS` is capable of recovering some of the information due to its inherent redundancy, we can do this by scrubbing.

```
BTRFS error (device sda1): bdev /dev/sda1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 11382, gen 0
BTRFS error (device sda1): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 13787648000 on dev /dev/sda1
```

In the case that the `superblock` is affected, you will not be able to mount at all. The `superblock` is the root of the `filesystem tree` and contains the information that the operating system needs to mount the unit. This is normally easy to fix because `BTRFS` saves extra copies at different locations, so you might be able to mount using a copy of a superblock, or even run below command to try to fix it.

```
btrfs rescue super-recover
```

Also you could be in the situation where the `filesystem` metadata is damaged even though the actual data might be intact. This means that `BTRFS` doesn’t know about the existence of files or parts of files so you have no way to access them. In this scenario, if you react quickly, you can scan the whole disk and try to rebuild the `filesystem` metadata tree with `btrfs`

```
rescue chunk-recover.
```

This is risky and very slow.

[How to recover a BTRFS partition](https://ownyourbits.com/2019/03/03/how-to-recover-a-btrfs-partition/)